# Multiple total and/or head rows in Excel table possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible to have more than one total or head row in an Excel 2010 table (formatted table, not plain worksheet)?

I know this is possible in Numbers '09 for OS X, but I could not find anything about Excel except a forum post where the answer questioned the validity of the question itself.

Normally, you have a table with a head row (for column titles), several normal data rows and a total row (for sum or average over all data rows per column). Sometimes the data is more complicated, for example imagine a list of running expenses over a month, where each row is a different day and you want to see the total sum of expenses, but also have a budget and want to see if your expenses are inside this budget.

The table would look something like this, where rows 1 and 2 would be head rows and 7 and 8 would be total rows.

```
    A        B       C     
  =========================
 1| Month  | Jan   | Feb  |
  -------------------------
 2| Budget | 10000 | 8000 |
  =========================
 3| Day 1  | 200   | 150  |
 4| Day 2  | 500   | 200  |
 5| Day 3  | 1000  | 500  |
 6| Day 4  | 500   | 200  |
  =========================
 7| SumExp | 2300  | 1050 |
  -------------------------
 8| Diff   | 7700  | 6950 |
  =========================
```

How can this be accomplished? Alternatively, if it is not possible, what layout would you suggest in this case?

Comment: Here is a feature request: https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/30978847-multiple-total-rows-in-tables

Answer (score 1):

I don't konw how exactly it looks like / how easy to achieve in "Numbers", there is no straight solution for that in Excel.

A workaround can be:

- formula for "SumExp": `=SUMIF($A$2:$A6,"<>budget",B$2:B6)`
- formula for "Diff": `=B$2-B7`
- this way you can add delete rows between rows 2 and 6 (can't add between 6 and 7) and calculations will stay correct.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestion. In Numbers you simply select the row and choose the option from the context menu. Quite useful for tables that break down categories into sub-categories, for example weeks in the first column, days of week in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I just wondered the same question and came up with a workaround:

```
"SummExp" & CHAR(10) & REPT("-",10) & CHAR(10) & "Diff"
```

and for the total rows something like,

```
=TEXT(SUBTOTAL(109,[SummExp-Jan]), "#,##0") &
 CHAR(10) & REPT("-", 10) & CHAR(10) &
 ROUND((SUBTOTAL(109,[SummExp-Jan]) / SUBTOTAL(109,[SummExp-Yr])) * 100, 1) & "%"
```

which ends up looking like,

```
 1,234
```

---

```
  9.5%
```

Hope this helps